# keyword that have space in lucene search?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, lucene.net

I use lucene in my ASP.NET MVC website for searching but I have a problem with some keyword that have spaces in the keyword search.

When I have **AB CD** for example and search **AB** I get the right answer but when search is exactly **AB CD** I don't get the right result.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Replace the space. Use AB_CD.

Comment: Are you still interested in an answer/approach for this?